# How do you set a tab to active class in Materialize CSS through Jquery in Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, materialize

I am currently trying to trigger a select of a tab in my materialize css tab menu. Everytime I try to use what is in the documentation to have a tab selected based on jquery logic I do not see anything selected until I click the tab. If someone could help me out on what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

```
ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.tabs').tabs();
      $('.tabs').tabs('select','test1');
    });     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `class = active` to the tab you want to be selected via jQuery.

Refer this documentation - http://materializecss.com/tabs.html